# Is it possible to query a 3D object from a database to unity scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am not expert at Unity yet and I have an idea to present on 7th of August. I am a little worried about the feasibility of my idea.

My question is as follow:
1) is it possible to query 3d object from a database to unity scene?

if the answer to above question is yes, will I be able to add the components to it when adding it?

Your feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible an here's what to do:

**1**.Store the 3D object as a binary data in the database in its original format such as `.fbx` and `.obj`.

**2**.When you need to retrieve it, don't connect directly to your database directly from Unity. Connect to your server which has a script(php) that retrieves the 3D object from a database. You can do this with a POST request using the [`UnityWebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025) API and a form that specifies which 3D object you want to retrieve. Your server code(php)should the connect to the database, retrieve the 3D object then return it your Unity app.

**3**.Create a new GameObject to hold the 3D object. Attach `MeshRenderer` and `MeshFilter` to it with the `GameObject.AddComponent` function then create new material for it. Load the 3D object with `FastObjImporter` and assign the mesh `MeshFilter`. This step is basically covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865014/load-and-display-obj-model-on-the-scene-with-fastobjimporter/47866947#47866947). Depending on the 3D object format, you may need a different plugin to convert it it Unity's mesh format. The `FastObjImporter` plugin is for `.obj` format.